# Detecting/handling WCF errors on manually created WCF proxy (via DuplexChannelFactory)

Tags: c#, wcf

I am creating a server/client application and I am calling WCF service methods via manually created proxy (using DuplexChannelFactory).
When calling certain methods on my WCF service my client mysteriously fails with System.ServiceModel.CommunicationObjectFaultedException. Additional information: The communication object, System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel, cannot be used for communication because it is in the Faulted state.

Currently the only thing I can do is turn on WCF tracing/logging and take a look at the .svclog file generated in the background.

This might give me more information such as this:
The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded. To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize property on the appropriate binding element. ---&gt; System.ServiceModel.QuotaExceededException: The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded. To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize property on the appropriate binding element.

On the server side I could probably add an instance of IErrorHandler and I could probably get this error there but AFAIK there is nothing I can do on the client side.

Is there a way on how can I get a hold of WCF exception information on the proxy client?